# How to print the array values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, replace

How i can replace the `array` values in php

```
 Array ([0] => Array ([ss] => k))
```

into

```
 array("0" => array ("ss" => "k"));
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow.com, please go through the existing questions and answers, there's a huge probability that you will find your answer without posting any new question.

Comment: This is just a hunch, since your question is not very clear, but are you looking for the [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function?

Answer (score 3):

You have to write you own function to output the format you like.

While the nearest solution with build-in function is `var_export`.

```
$array = array(array('ss' => 'k'));
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'ss' => 'k',
  ),
)
```

Comment: *sidenote:* if the OP wants to further manipulate the output, he can save the output of `var_export` by passing `true` in 2nd parameter of the function, i.e. `$output = var_export($array, true);`. Then, OP can play with `$output`.