# print array value in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a php array value but i don't know how to print it. there is my php code

```
$json = array();
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    while($result = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json[] = $result;
    }
}
```

And here is my array value

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [locationid] => 1
        [locationname] => Anantapur
        [locationvalue] => 1.1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [locationid] => 2
        [locationname] => Guntakal
        [locationvalue] => 1.2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [locationid] => 4
        [locationname] => Guntur
        [locationvalue] => 1.3
    )
)
```

I'm Trying like

```
echo $json['locationname'];
```

But It's Not working please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the array values in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688928/how-to-print-the-array-values-in-php)

Comment: What output you need?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `loop` through your `array` first. Try `foreach`

```
foreach($json as $j){
    echo $j['locationname']; 
}
```

Comment: IS there any other option

Comment: what type of option you are looking for??

Answer (score 1):

You have not need to make a new array after get the result. you can print your value within the loop

```
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
   while($result = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $result['locationaname'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The array you created is associative array. For loo through these type of arrays requires foreach. Visit http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($json AS $key =>$value){
     echo $value['locationname'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly print the value of location, instead of creating a new array, unless you need it further.

```
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    while($result = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $result['locationname'];
    }
}
```

if you want to have $json, which is an associative array, you need to get into it, looping through it.

```
foreach($json as $key => $value){
    echo $value['locationname'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want json string try this:

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

after your loop.