# How to print an array in php?

Tags: php, html

I need to print some cards in html, but I'll receive a php array with the number of days I'll have to print.
I've tried this, but isn't working.

```
<div>
<div class="row" style="padding: 0px 30px">
    <?php foreach ($array as $num):?>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title"><?php $num ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: this is my arrays:
<?php
 $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
 $days = array("segunda","terça","quarta","quinta","sexta");
?>

Comment: [edit] your question please. __Do not post code in comments__.

Comment: Replace `<?php $num ?>` with `<?= $num ?>`. Check [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: "it isn't working" is not a helpful problem statement.  What _is_ happening?  In what way is that different from what you want/expect?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: Try <?php echo $days[0]; ?> Replace the number 0 with the specific index you want to echo/display.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print array value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440425/print-array-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these loops will help:

```
foreach ($array as $mykey=>$myval) {
    echo $myval;
}

foreach ($array as $mykey=>$myval) {
    echo $array[$mykey];
}
```